# Get Member of an Object in Swift using Variables

Tags: swift, swift2

For context, this is a goal tracking app, where you aim to check in for 7 consecutive days, earning a streak. It's written in Swift2

I have an instance of an Object stored in the variable `let latestStreak`

**Problem:**
I can't figure how to check the value of a particular Day of the streak we are on. I also want to determine which Day to check using variables. Here's where I'm at and what I mean.

`print(latestStreak)` outputs this:

```
(Streak {
    id = 0;
    Owner = Goal {
        id = 0;
        Goal = Goal;
        Habit = Habit;
        CreatedOn = 2016-02-17 00:00:47 +0000;
    };
    StartDate = 2016-02-17 00:00:47 +0000;
    Day1 = 1;
    Day2 = 0;
    Day3 = 1;
    Day4 = 0;
    Day5 = 0;
    Day6 = 0;
    Day7 = 0;
    Completed = 0;
})
```

I have a function which calculates how many days we are at since the StartDate. For the point of example, if StartDate is today, `Day = 0`.

I then have created a string to correspond to the correct member of an object: `let streakDay = "Day"+String(days+1)` which might output something like this: `Day1`.

I now want to do:

```
if(latestStreak.Day1 == 1){...do something}else{...}
```

However, I can't figure out how to set `latestStreak.Day1` using variables. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create (compounded) variable names at runtime because all variables have to be evaluated at compile time.

A suitable "workaround" is to use an array and access the items by index.